# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)

Tags: ruby, sass

I'm trying to install sass. But not able to install.
Im facing this issue.

```
 C:\Users\Administrator>gem install sass
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was aborted by the software i
n your host machine. - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/sass-
3.4.13.gemspec.rz)
```

Comment: You are within the great firewall in China. See [this](https://www.zfanw.com/blog/error-while-executing-gem-gem-remote-fetch-error.html)